# ibm - bluemix - node-red - app is not running and I can't add analytics service

Tags: hadoop, ibm-cloud, node-red

I am following the simple tutorial given below: [Collect and analyze social data without writing a single line of code](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/analytics/library/ba-collect-analyze-social-data-app/index.html?cm_mmc=dw-_-trs-_-social-_-generic)

As per the link, the node-red app should be added. But after adding it the status is showing as **"Your app status is unknown"**. And if I ignore this `error` and go ahead in adding the "IBM Analytics for Hadoop" - the app doesnt appear in the selection, i.e I am not able to create the service also.

Can you please advise... what I should do to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Satish,

there seems to be a problem with deploying from the Node-RED Starter boilerplate. I just tried it and fail, too, and when I check the logs I see there is an error that somebody needs to investigate so I have opened a ticket for this a couple of minutes ago.

Anyway, even if the deployment would work you wouldn't be able to complete the tutorial: since Romeo wrote it, the Analytics for Hadoop service has been upgraded. Part of the tutorial is no longer correct and last I checked there was a problem with the HDFS node in Node-RED on Bluemix in that it could no longer connect to Hadoop.

Regards, Harald

Comment: I've just deployed an instance of the node-red boilerplate without a problem. The HDFS node ought to be updated in the next few days.

Comment: Your kharma is way better than mine. I tried it three times an hour ago, two times I was able to check the logs and it failed during install of node-red-nodes-cf-sqldb. Just now tried it again and the boilerplate deploys.

Answer (score 0):

Satish,
Try with the Analytics for Apache Hadoop service. The latest fix for HDFS node should help. I am attaching the Node-RED source for your reference.

```
[
{
    "id": "19e3fecb.c535b9",
    "type": "inject",
    "name": "",
    "topic": "",
    "payload": "",
    "payloadType": "date",
    "repeat": "",
    "crontab": "",
    "once": false,
    "x": 311,
    "y": 109,
    "z": "d2f1fb2c.6dc9f",
    "wires": [
        [
            "e260889a.2a8a3"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "997c2459.ada828",
    "type": "ibm hdfs",
    "name": "",
    "filename": "/welcome.txt",
    "appendNewline": false,
    "overwriteFile": true,
    "x": 660,
    "y": 112,
    "z": "d2f1fb2c.6dc9f",
    "wires": []
},
{
    "id": "e260889a.2a8a3",
    "type": "function",
    "name": "",
    "func": "msg.payload = {\"d\":{\"voltage\":240}};\nreturn msg;",
    "outputs": 1,
    "noerr": 0,
    "x": 464,
    "y": 122,
    "z": "d2f1fb2c.6dc9f",
    "wires": [
        [
            "997c2459.ada828"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "f18b36e9.11256",
    "type": "inject",
    "name": "",
    "topic": "",
    "payload": "",
    "payloadType": "date",
    "repeat": "",
    "crontab": "",
    "once": false,
    "x": 322,
    "y": 194.9999771118164,
    "z": "d2f1fb2c.6dc9f",
    "wires": [
        [
            "ea15a346.645838"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "3cf35d10.b5b02a",
    "type": "ibm hdfs in",
    "name": "",
    "filename": "/welcome.txt",
    "format": "utf8",
    "x": 670,
    "y": 205.9999771118164,
    "z": "d2f1fb2c.6dc9f",
    "wires": [
        [
            "8c4333f4.7545b"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "8c4333f4.7545b",
    "type": "debug",
    "name": "",
    "active": true,
    "console": "false",
    "complete": "payload",
    "x": 871,
    "y": 201.9999771118164,
    "z": "d2f1fb2c.6dc9f",
    "wires": []
},
{
    "id": "ea15a346.645838",
    "type": "function",
    "name": "",
    "func": "msg.filename = \"/welcome.txt\";\nreturn msg;",
    "outputs": 1,
    "noerr": 0,
    "x": 479,
    "y": 203.9999771118164,
    "z": "d2f1fb2c.6dc9f",
    "wires": [
        [
            "3cf35d10.b5b02a"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "1ba399e.a2a5ae6",
    "type": "inject",
    "name": "",
    "topic": "",
    "payload": "",
    "payloadType": "date",
    "repeat": "",
    "crontab": "",
    "once": false,
    "x": 326,
    "y": 368.9999771118164,
    "z": "d2f1fb2c.6dc9f",
    "wires": [
        [
            "4d84ea75.52b5bc"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "4d84ea75.52b5bc",
    "type": "function",
    "name": "",
    "func": "msg.delete = true;\nreturn msg;",
    "outputs": 1,
    "noerr": 0,
    "x": 500,
    "y": 373.00000762939453,
    "z": "d2f1fb2c.6dc9f",
    "wires": [
        [
            "e9c07b8e.d458f"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "e9c07b8e.d458f",
    "type": "ibm hdfs",
    "name": "",
    "filename": "/welcome.txt",
    "appendNewline": true,
    "overwriteFile": false,
    "x": 693,
    "y": 368.9999771118164,
    "z": "d2f1fb2c.6dc9f",
    "wires": []
},
{
    "id": "dd7bf27a.2a122",
    "type": "comment",
    "name": "Create",
    "info": "",
    "x": 171.00001525878906,
    "y": 108.99999237060547,
    "z": "d2f1fb2c.6dc9f",
    "wires": []
},
{
    "id": "e384dc30.7d9188",
    "type": "comment",
    "name": "Read",
    "info": "",
    "x": 177.00001525878906,
    "y": 196.99999237060547,
    "z": "d2f1fb2c.6dc9f",
    "wires": []
},
{
    "id": "c082c1.4e78054",
    "type": "comment",
    "name": "Delete",
    "info": "",
    "x": 171.00001525878906,
    "y": 365.9999771118164,
    "z": "d2f1fb2c.6dc9f",
    "wires": []
},
{
    "id": "fd160f73.d01508",
    "type": "inject",
    "name": "",
    "topic": "",
    "payload": "",
    "payloadType": "date",
    "repeat": "",
    "crontab": "",
    "once": false,
    "x": 319.00001525878906,
    "y": 280.00000762939453,
    "z": "d2f1fb2c.6dc9f",
    "wires": [
        [
            "215a640f.5b3a64"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "3362cea6.d2a8a2",
    "type": "ibm hdfs",
    "name": "",
    "filename": "/welcome.txt",
    "appendNewline": true,
    "overwriteFile": false,
    "x": 668.0000152587891,
    "y": 283.00000762939453,
    "z": "d2f1fb2c.6dc9f",
    "wires": []
},
{
    "id": "215a640f.5b3a64",
    "type": "function",
    "name": "",
    "func": "msg.payload = {\"d\":{\"voltage\":240}};\nreturn msg;",
    "outputs": 1,
    "noerr": 0,
    "x": 472.00001525878906,
    "y": 293.00000762939453,
    "z": "d2f1fb2c.6dc9f",
    "wires": [
        [
            "3362cea6.d2a8a2"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "4ccf2efd.fa95e8",
    "type": "comment",
    "name": "Update",
    "info": "Update",
    "x": 179.00003051757812,
    "y": 280,
    "z": "d2f1fb2c.6dc9f",
    "wires": []
}]
```

Bind / Add the service before deploying the flow.

Thanks and Regards
Amit M Mangalvedkar

Answer (score 0):

Satish,

For the issue you are seeing it seems that the adding/removing of services may have caused an issue.  When services are changed around sometimes the bluemix-settings.js does not sync up properly and you will need to download the source code, update it and push your application back up. If you are just in the beginning of creating the app I would suggest to start from scratch with removing the boilerplate and then creating the new app. This will clear up any issues.

Here is a simpler example of analyzing twitter data without a line of code and not needing to add any services beyond what is added when you create a node-RED boilerplate: [Link to Developer Works Article](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/11/02/analyze-tweets-in-30-minutes/).